# How to Convert MP4 to HLS with Multiple Audio and Multiple Video Quality in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-on-demand

I have tried with **ffmpeg library** and I can convert videos mp4 to hls with multiple quality but multiple audio is not working. > [Commands Excuting from Terminal]

And with **subprocess library** calling `subprocess.call`. > [ Want to know is this the right way? to do with Django? ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution https://github.com/aminyazdanpanah/python-ffmpeg-video-streaming

Read the documentation and modify as your requirement.